# Save data to AppData and share it between other projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, datastore

Is there anyway to save some data and then share it between Unity3D projects?

I was thinking about Application.persistentDataPath but it always use Company Name and Product Name, and create a new folder for every application I run.

e.g.

```
AppData/CompanyName/Game1/...
AppData/CompanyName/Game2/...
AppData/CompanyName/Game3/...
```

and my goal is to store everything in one folder, like this:

```
AppData/CompanyName/...
```

Comment: Have a look https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own method to make it.

```
public static string GetSharedApplicationPersistentDataPath()
{
    string appDataWithProductName = Application.persistentDataPath;
    string toReplace = Application.productName;

    return result = appDataWithProductName.Replace(toReplace, "");
}
```